# What should I do about this question?

Tags: discussion, questions, question-appropriateness, specific-question

To begin with, see [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/207565/287239). Note that it has no answers. Note also that I no longer care about the question, and would probably accept any answer, as the problem at hand has been fixed. Finally, note that I earned the tumbleweed badge from this question.

Given this, how should I proceed? Should I...

1. Ignore it
2. Delete it
3. Petition to close it
4. Put an answer and accept it so it no longer clogs up the 'unanswered' queue.

Comment: I'd go with "4": It's neither off-topic, low quality or unanswerable (as you have an answer). If you post the answer, it might help someone else in a similar situation.

Answer (score 3):

I'd start with this:

> ... as the problem at hand has been fixed ...

Yes, if you solved a problem yourself, you're always encouraged to post a self-answer (and accept it if appropriate).

The goal of Stack Exchange is to build a library of knowledge to help not only the question asker, but more importantly, all *future* visitors to the sites. Therefore any potentially useful question and solution (answer) should not be left out *just because* no one cares at present. It's meant to be valuable to the future.

On the other hand, neither option 2 nor option 3 would be appropriate, as the question is of a decent shape and doesn't warrant closure or deletion. Option 1 may be acceptable, but why would you ignore it when there are better options available? `:)`

Congrats on your first self-answer then!

---

This answer probably looks like an expanded version of [Izzy's comment](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2532/what-should-i-do-about-this-question#comment6779_2532), but I believe that it'd be because this is the general feeling or consensus that the Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange community would have.